# Why does my internal hard-drive fail to mount on boot if a USB memory stick is plugged in?

Tags: hard-drive, fedora, automount

I have a second internal hard-drive which fails to automatically mount if I have a USB stick plugged in when I boot, despite the following line in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sdd2   /data2  ext4  defaults
```

If there is no USB device plugged in, the internal drive mounts normally.
Any ideas on how I can fix this?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because when the USB stick is plugged in, it gets detected ahead of the internal drive that you refer to as /dev/sdd, so the sdX identifiers get shifted around.

The way to solve this is to use a non-volatile identifier. Either use one of the names in one of `/dev/disk/by-*/` (I like /dev/disk/by-id, since those are reasonably human-readable, but other names may be more useful in your particular situation), or use `blkid`/`dumpe2fs` and a `UUID=...` specifier for the file system, in place of the `/dev/sdd2` partition specifier that you currently have.

Comment: The names in /dev/disk/by-label were very useful, as they reflect the names I actually gave the hard drives. Cheers!